# Google Sites and Google Chart Tools

Tags: google-visualization, google-sites

I'm trying to include a Google Chart Tools dashboard in a Google Site.

The problem is **what code to include in Google Site's html box**. I've tried different variations using the code below, but I keep getting

```
failed to load external URL jsapi
```

The code works perfectly inside an html file loaded directly, but not in Google Site's html box.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this with app script:

["Currently, Google Sites does not allow the use of JavaScript, iFrames or CSS tags because the use of these languages could leave your site open to security risks. If not protected against, these forms of code could allow people to insert malicious code that could harm you or visitors to your site."](http://support.google.com/sites/answer/90540?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks. It just dawned on me that app script isn't javascript...I have a lot to learn...

Comment: It does work: insert script gadget, then paste the published script link (exported as web app from google docs). The following links explains how to get app script to generate html. [link](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_gadgets#embedding) [link](http://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service)